# XSL Transformation in Java with parameters

Tags: java, xslt

I have a xsl file where i need to use parameters from an external source. I am using Java and my code looks something like this:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer xsltTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
xsltTransformer.setParameter(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

However, an exception is thrown at the 2nd line - *Variable or parameter 'variable_name' is undefined.* I realize that XSL is compiled and is probably compiled when the transformer is created.

So, how do i pass parameters to my transformation? How is the setParameter method supposed to be used?

Comment: Double check to make sure you spelled the parameterName properly and that the cAsE matches what is declared in the XSLT.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you pass a parameter like:

```
transformer.setParameter("render_id", "1234");
```

the parameter can be picked up by the transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- Receives the id of the menu being rendered. -->
<xsl:param name="render_id" />
```

Comment: Great Ans, FYI if the parameter has any value in the xsl it will be ignored and the one sent by Java will take precedence

Answer (score 2):

rsp's answer was spot on. Thanks.
Just want to add that you cannot pass a parameter to a variable in the same way (I am setting parameters via Java's TransformerFactory).

I made the mistake of thinking variables and params were interchangeable :)

Comment: Here's a good answer about differences between `param` and `variable`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854157/1813669