# difference between xsl:param and xsl:variable

Tags: xslt, parameters

I am considering using either `<xsl:param>` or `<xsl:variable>` when defining an `<xsl:template name="myTemplate">` that will be called in another XSL file.

Legacy code seems to use `xsl:variable` when being used in `<xsl:template match="legacyTemplate">`.

So what's the difference between `xsl:param` and `xsl:variable` when using it in `<xsl:template name="myTemplate">`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The difference is that the value of an `xsl:param` could be
set outside the context in which it is declared.  For example,
see:

```
<xsl:template ...>
   <xsl:param name="p" select="'x'" />
   <xsl:variable name="v" select="'y'" />
...
```

then you know that `$v` will always give you the string `'y'`.  But for `$p` the string `'x'` is only a default:
you will see a different value if the template is invoked with either
`xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:call-template` which contains an instruction
such as:
   `<xsl:with-param name="p" select="'not x'" />`

`<xsl:param>` may also be used outside `xsl:template`, at the top level in
the stylesheet.  The value of such a parameter may be set when the
XSLT processor is called.  How this is done depends on the processor
and whether you call it from the command line or by program.