# Setting xslt hidden value from java

Tags: java, xslt

New to xslt, I wanted to set a value of string from java to this variable

```
<xsl:element name="input">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">hidden</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">trackId</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="trackValue"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
```

Is it in same manner as html or is it different apprach? Thanks for help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass values into your XSLT using parameters.  What you would do is define a parameter near the top of your XSLT file:

```
<xsl:param name="trackValue" />
```

And then you would pass in a value for this when you run the transform:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer xsltTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
xsltTransformer.setParameter("trackValue", parameterValue);
```

Then you can use it wherever you want to (note the use of the $ sign):

```
<xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$trackValue"/></xsl:attribute>
```

[XSL Transformation in Java with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1667454/1945651)