# How to add a non-printable image in xsl / apache-fop

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate an xsl to be printed in a pre-printed sheet which works fine.

Now i want to give the user a better previsualization (in the pdf screen version) adding a background image which emulates the "pre-printed" stuf on the sheet to give the user a "context" of what is he printing.

The question is: Is there any way I can set a background image in xsl (using apache fop) visible only in pdf but not in the printed version of it?

Thank you all for reading or givin any advice.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible at all. A PDF is meant to describe the content of a document, completely independently of the device that is used - should it be a screen, or any kind of printer of any brand. Thus you can't have a feature like you require. The only mean would be to generate two different PDF files.

Comment: I was afraid of that but was hoping someone had found a trick

Answer (score 0):

Although as the comments state, you can't have content in the PDF that does not come out in a physical printed copy, here is one possible work around for you. Depending on how your users are ultimately going to be using FOP for PDF rendering and how your a driving the work flow, it's possible to pass a parameter into an xslt file before the transofrmation phase is run, so potentially, you could do a dual rendering of the same PDF, one that is presented to the user where the background image is enabled, and one that gets printed, you could just set a variable similar to how they do in [this Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667454/xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters/%22this%20example%22), and call it something like $isPreview, and just use a simple if or choose statement to check for 'Y' or 'N'.

Since you are sending to a printer, you may even want to take advantage of FOP's ability to generate to Postscript rather than PDF, I've used this feature quite extensively for print documents using FOP while also producing a PDF copy for electronic delivery via email or hosted services, and I've yet to find any discrepancy between the PDF rendering and what is printed after sending a rendered postscript file, so it should work well for you as well.

As I said, this is not truly a solution to your problem as you've presented it, but as a work around, it could get you the desired results if your clever about how you implement it.

Comment: The problem is that I present the pdf in an iframe and usually the "print" button is the one offered by browser :(

Comment: In that case you should see if you can overlay an image using CSS in the iframe so that you only see the image in the iframe, forget about inserting the image into the PDF, take advantage of the existing web technologies to make it appear as tho it is there, but when you print the PDF, it should not print on the final copy because the PDF itself does not contain the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think the statement that it is not possible is true, I am just not sure how to create such a PDF *with* FOP. Certainly you can add an image *field*. One would use a button field and place the image in the button. Then you would set the properties of that button to not print (printable false).

PDF support images in fields: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/adding-image-field-form-q41825.aspx

RenderX supports PDF Form fields but I do not see where they support an image inside the button, only text: http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#PDF%20Forms. But they do support setting a field to "printable".

Comment: Not likely this works on apache-fop but I will take a look. Thank for the suggestion