# Modify tag content with XSL

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>blabla1</groupId>
        <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
        <version>if strArtifactId equals test1, put iVersion value here</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>blabla2</groupId>
        <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
        <version>if strArtifactId equals test2, put iVersion value here</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>blabla3</groupId>
        <artifactId>test3</artifactId>
        <version>if strArtifactId equals test3, put iVersion value here</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the following XSL :

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="strArtifactID"/>
  <xsl:param name="iVersion"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="artifactId">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$strArtifactID"/>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="version">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$iVersion"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need to do is to replace the version tag of a dependency with my parameters

strArtifactId : choose which dependency version will be modified.

iVersion : the version that I want.

Both parameters are given by a GUI.

**The problem** : When I launch my code, it only copy the original xml, but nothing change.

Any help please ?

Comment: Expected output with complete input XML please..

Answer (score 0):

The XML you provided was incomplete, so I added a `<root>` node around the `<dependency>` nodes in your code sample to make it valid XML.

So your XML then looks like this:

```
<root>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>blabla1</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>if strArtifactId equals test1, put iVersion value here</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>blabla2</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>if strArtifactId equals test2, put iVersion value here</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>blabla3</groupId>
    <artifactId>test3</artifactId>
    <version>if strArtifactId equals test3, put iVersion value here</version>
  </dependency>
</root>
```

Here is the XSL stylesheet that will give you the result you are looking for based on your XML conforming to the example above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="strArtifactID" />
  <xsl:param name="iVersion" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dependency">
    <dependency>
      <xsl:copy-of select="groupId" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="artifactId" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="artifactId = $strArtifactID">
          <version><xsl:value-of select="format-number($iVersion, '#.0')" /></version>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="version" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </dependency>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So what is happening in the stylesheet is:

1. Your 'strArtifactID' and 'iVersion' param values are set by the GUI you mentioned ( I assigned values to them using select="'test1'" and select="1.0" after the name values, just for testing purposes).
2. The identity template makes an exact copy of your XML.
3. The `<dependency>` nodes are rebuilt in the format you want ( steps 4, 5, 6 ).
4. The `<groupId>` and `<artifactId>` nodes are simply copied because their contents do not change.
5. When the `<artifactId>` node value within a `<dependency>` matches the value of the 'strArtifactID' param value, a `<version>` node is created containing the 'iVersion' param value (which I have assumed is numerical, and have formatted to keep one decimal place).
6. When the `<artifactId>` node value within a `<dependency>` does not match the value of the 'strArtifactID' param value, the existing `<version>` node is copied.

Comment: The xsl above is correct. I can't comment on your Java code, but this may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667454/xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters

Comment: Thanks, but when I debug the xsl code, it never reach the `<xsl:template match="dependency">`

 it stays in the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Can you please show me your complete xml? Getting the xsl to work for you should be as simple as changing the 'match' value, but I need to see your complete xml to help you with this.

Comment: I have to modify my XML so it will be ok I think when it will be done. If there is another problem  I will post. Thanks you a lot