# XSLT report customization

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to generate my Selenium test automation reports. I am using testNG framework for that. I believe XSLT generates reports based on the testNG result file.
What my requirement is, using my code I am getting the version number of the AUT(Application under test). I want to display this version number in XSLT reports. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using [`<xsl:param>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_param.asp) you can pass external strings as arguments to your xslt.

Comment: Instead of writing string straightly there I want to get that from java code, which means, from my AUT i stored version number in a string called version_number. By passing this version_number variable to XSLT report, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, if you will use the transformation in java, here is an example on how to make the call: [xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667454/xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters)

Comment: I am unable to give the xslt-results.xsl file path in the Trasnformer Class. What path exactly we have to give at 'xsltSource' in link you provided.