# setOutputProperty(), setParameter() and setURIResolver() methods of javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

What is the use of the methods `setOutputProperty()`, `setParameter()` and `setURIResolver()` of the class `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`? I had went through the official documentation and many other online resources, but I was unable to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from the documentation because they don't link it prominently (but subtly), but `setOutputProperty` refers to [OutputKeys](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html), and those values can be used for the property names (and contain information about what they do, like control the indentation of the output).

`setParameter` makes a parameter value available to the transform; see [XSL Transformation in Java with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667454/xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters).

`setURIResolver` allows the caller to specify how to find URIs. This might, for example, be used to load public identifiers like `-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML//EN`; see [Formal Public Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Public_Identifier), or to load network resources from a local filesystem or database.