# Apache fop, XSL FO, jdom2: generate pdf with dynamic header/footer

Tags: java, xsl-fo, jdom

I generate a .pdf from java object and I'd like to pass values from java object to my header/footer in .xsl.
Here's a part of my .xsl:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="content">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="Header">
        <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" font-size="8pt">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden" > Œ
                        <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                                        Supplier’s name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                                        Supplier’s code: <xsl:param name="supplierCodeLol" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:static-content flow-name="Footer">              
        <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" font-size="8pt">
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden" >
                        <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                                        Export requestor: <xsl:param name="exportRequestor" />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden">
                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-size="10pt">
            <xsl:for-each select="block">
                <xsl:call-template name="block-template" select="."></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block id="theEnd" />
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Where I create the .pdf:

```
public void convertToPDF(String xml, String fileName) throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File xsltFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("template/xml/xsl_test.xsl").getFile());
    StreamSource xmlSource;
    if (xml == null) {
        xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(classLoader.getResource("template/xml/xml_test.xml").getFile()));
    } else {
        xmlSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    }

    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    OutputStream out;
    out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fileName);

    try {
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
    }
```

This is where I create and fill .pdf with java object (header part):

```
public String exportPlaneToPdfa(PLANE plane, UserBean user, String fileName) {
    PdfHelper pdfHelper = new PdfHelper();
    Document doc = new Document(toXmlElement(plane, userName));
    XMLOutputter outter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    String xml = outter.outputString(doc);
    pdfHelper.convertToPDF(xml, "/" + fileName);
    return fileName;
}

private Element toXmlElement(PlaneBean plane, String userName) {
    Element planeRoot = new Element(XmlHelper.PLANE);
    XmlHelper.addAllContents(planeRoot, toHeaderXmlElement(plane));
    return planeRoot;
}

private Element toHeaderXmlElement(PlaneBean plane) {
    Element header = new Element(XmlHelper.BLOCK);
    header.setAttribute(XmlHelper.NAME, "Equipment");

    Element row = new Element(XmlHelper.ROW);
    XmlHelper.addAllContents(row,
        XmlHelper.newFieldElement("Supplier's name", plane.name),
        XmlHelper.newFieldElement("Supplier's code", plane.code)));
    XmlHelper.addAllContents(header, row);
    return header;
}
```

The .pdf output (header):
[image: pdf header output]

Create a block and display it works but I don't know how to pass block's values to header.
I searched for xsl:value-of/param but I do not know if that's the way to do it. Thanks a lot for your help !

EDIT:
I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667454/xsl-transformation-in-java-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

To get you started.
You can declare a `xsl:param name="someName"` as child of the `xsl:stylesheet`. And then use it as a global variable `xsl:value-of select="$someName"`

i.e. like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="supplierCodeLol" />
  <xsl:param name="exportRequestor" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="content">
      <fo:static-content flow-name="Header">
        <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" font-size="8pt">
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden" > Œ
                <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                  Supplier’s name: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                  Supplier’s code: <xsl:value-of select="$supplierCodeLol" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:static-content>
      
      <fo:static-content flow-name="Footer">              
        <fo:table border-collapse="collapse" font-size="8pt">
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden" >
                <fo:block vertical-align="middle" margin-left="0.2cm" text-align="left">
                  Export requestor: <xsl:value-of select="$exportRequestor" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" overflow="hidden">
                <fo:block></fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:static-content>
      
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-size="10pt">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="block"/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block id="theEnd" />
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>

  
  <xsl:template match="block">
    <!-- Do something with the block -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Once it's done, how do you pass param's value from objet to .xsl ?